# asp.net core web api how to send json object from client side c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, console, client-server

this is my client code

```
var client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BASE_URL);
            var multipart = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            var jsonToSend = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(template, Formatting.None);
            var body = new StringContent(jsonToSend, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            multipart.Add(body, "JsonDetails");
            return client.PostAsync("jsons", multipart);
```

server code is

```
 [HttpPost("jsons")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> RequestJson([FromBody]Person person)
        {

        if (person != null)
        {
            return Ok("true");
        }


        return Ok("false");
```

person code

```
public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Position { get; set; }
    }
```

when look in debug my post from client dont knock to server, in postman my post sending and i can see my object property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just post the StringContent directly without the Multipart-Form:

```
var client = new HttpClient
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri(BASE_URL)
};

var jsonToSend = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(template, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None);

var body = new StringContent(jsonToSend, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

return client.PostAsync("jsons", body)
```